# Python re.match Issue

Tags: python, regex

Here's what my code looks like...

```
if re.match('[a-z]',usrInput):
    run onlyLetters function
elif re.match('[0-9]',usrInput):
    run onlyNumbers function
elif re.match('[a-z0-9]',usrInput):
    run lettersAndNums function
```

The problem is, if I enter text such as `'2394jsdkfjsdkm'`, it will read as onlyLetters because it satisfies the first condition in the if statement. I would really like an input like this to be lettersAndNums. How do I need to alter the code?

Comment: Suggest you read the manual.  It has lots of good examples that would help you solve this (simple) problem.  http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to see if a string is all numbers, letters, or alphanumeric:

```
if usrInput.isalpha():
    # all letters
elif usrInput.isdigit():
    # all numbers
elif usrInput.isalnum():
    # all letters or numbers
```

Note that this allows both upper- and lowercase letters; if you want only lowercase letters add `and usrInput.islower()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only checks that the first character matches the pattern. If you want to make sure that *all* the characters in in string match the pattern, use `[pattern]*$`, like so:

```
if re.match('[a-z]*$',usrInput):
    run onlyLetters function
elif re.match('[0-9]*$',usrInput):
    run onlyNumbers function
elif re.match('[a-z0-9]*$',usrInput):
    run lettersAndNums function
```

This is because `*` means "any number of the character," and `$` means "end of the string."

Comment: these patterns will match an empty string. I think it is better to use `+` insead of `*`.